# Validate two interdependent input fields with ngModelController Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I want to validate two input values with one $validators attribute.
With respect to the $validators function only the ng-model value of the corresponding input fild is accessable with viewValue.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form name="reverInputForm" ng-submit="vm.insertReverInformation(reverInputForm)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label>
                Kühlung:<span style="color:red;">*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div ng-class="{'has-error':reverInputForm.reverProducerNameInput.$invalid && reverInputForm.$submitted}">
                <input name="reverProducerNameInput"
                       class="form-control"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Hersteller eingeben"
                       generalvalidations
                       ng-model="vm.ReverType.ReverProducer.Name"
                       ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}" />
                <div ng-messages="reverInputForm.reverProducerNameInput.$error"
                     ng-show="reverInputForm.$submitted"
                     style="padding:0.2% 0% 0.4% 0%">
                    <div class="label-danger small validationErrorBlock">
                        <div ng-messages-include="validation-error-messages" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            <label>
                Typ:<span style="color:red;">*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div ng-class="{'has-error':reverInputForm.reverTypNameInput.$invalid && reverInputForm.$submitted}">
                <input name="reverTypNameInput"
                       type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Typ eingeben"
                       generalvalidations
                       ng-model="vm.ReverType.Name"
                       ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}" />
                <div ng-messages="reverInputForm.reverTypNameInput.$error"
                     ng-show="reverInputForm.$submitted"
                     style="padding:0.2% 0% 0.4% 0%">
                    <div class="label-danger small validationErrorBlock">
                        <div ng-messages-include="validation-error-messages" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the custom validator is called generalvalidations. This validation contains as attribute inside both input fields.
the $validator looks like this:

```
var generalValidations;
(function (generalValidations)
{
    'use strict';
    var generalValidations = (function ()
    {
        function generalValidations($compile)
        {
            var _this = this;
            this.restrict = 'A';
            this.require = 'ngModel';
            generalValidations.prototype.link = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl)
            {
                ngModelCtrl.$validators.notEmpty = function (modelValue, viewValue)
                {
                    if (viewValue == '' || viewValue == null)
                        return false;
                    return true;
                };
            };
        }
        return generalValidations;
    }());
    generalValidations.generalValidations = generalValidations;
    angular.module('euroscan').directive('generalvalidations', function () { return new generalValidations(); });
})(generalValidations || (generalValidations = {}));
```

I know that the validaor will be called twice. But i want to be able to have access to both ng-model values at that times. Is there a common way i don't know. I think angularjs should provide a well defined solution. The scope for example does not contain the the second value.

Does anybody know?
Thanks for that.

Klement

Comment: I had a similar requirement and I don't remember all the details, so I won't put this as an answer, but I wrote a directive that knows about both inputs and when once changes it checked the sibling. I wish I had some code to show you, but I just wanted to give you something to think about..

Comment: Thank you for the fnformation. I think i'll gonna try a similar solution. I thought that angular provide a proper way. But if not your purpose sounds really good. ;-D

Comment: In my case I had a grid, each row in the grid had several input, 2 of the inputs were inter-related, one could not be greater than the other, so I had a parent directive on the TR which knew about all the input in the grid which has controllers, and the child knows about the parent controller and they all subscribed to an handler in the parent controller and when one was validated I would validate the siblings if they were not valid...